# Is this a Regexp bug or another thing?

Tags: ruby, regex

I was playing with Ruby's Regexp. I supposed find a Regexp trick, but I can't understand, why?

```
  p a = "This is a test!".gsub!(//,'X')
```

Output of above is

```
  "XTXhXiXsX XiXsX XaX XtXeXsXtX!X"
```

It puts 'X' after and before any character in the test string. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Especially when you are a beginner, don't easily suspect it is a bug. Much more likely, it is your misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes, i misunderstood this, but it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//` matches substrings with zero width, i.e., empty strings. There are arbitrarily many empty strings in between any adjacent characters, but the `gsub` family does not keep matching at the same location. If it finds a match (i.e., the empty string in this case), then it will not match again at the same position, so it goes on to the empty string that is in between the next adjacent characters.

Answer (score 2):

You asked it to match a zero-width string (`//`), and replace it with 'X', so it did that. `gsub` scans the string and replaces every match (every letter boundary) with the replacement.

Comment: You say everything except anything is nothing, but how do you know there is only one nothing between characters or each nothing include how many nothing?

Comment: By definition, when the regex engine looks at the first character, the only successful match is the 0-length match before the character (IOW, nothing). Since that is a successful match, it is passed to the gsub replacement ("X"), and then the scan steps forward, and starts again.

Comment: Your phrasing "nothing" is misleading. In Ruby, an empty string is not "nothing".

Comment: Fair enough. I figured nothing made sense, but clarified it here.

Answer (score 0):

You asked it to match an empty space, so it matches every null space between letters.

It does not match a letter so all the letters remained.

Comment: No. The letters remain because the pointer advances past them after each match.

Comment: @pguardiario so you mean they skip the letter and directly advance past them

Comment: Yes, the pointer has to advance after a match. Otherwise endless loop.